# How to run wmic command in a batch file

Tags: windows, wmic

I am running couple of wmic commands in a btach file to find a process and killing it.

wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%app1%'" Call Terminate

wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%app2%'" Call Terminate

These commands run fine when I run from console individually but when I run them using a batch file , I get error as below:

wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like ''" Call Terminate

No Instance(s) Available.

Can someone point out whats the issue with the command if its run from a batch file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Inside a batch file percent signs need to be escaped. The command you are trying to execute are seeing `%app1%` as a variable read and replaced with (probably) a empty string.

You need to use

```
wmic Path win32_process Where "CommandLine Like '%%app1%%'" Call Terminate
```

Note that this condition will also match the current `wmic` instance, as the search term is also included in its own command line. You should add an aditional test to ensure only the desired process is terminated.

Comment: thanks. just add double percent symbol to escape it.